# Change activity with action button click?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

How can I change activities with my action button?

```
package com.com.com;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//In order for this method to receive calls
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle presses on the action bar items
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_new1:
          Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);


          switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


          @Override

          public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this, Login.class);

          startActivity(intent);

          }

          });


          }   
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

This is my current code, but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please explain how to get this working? I know that I need this

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle presses on the action bar items
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_new1:
          openSearch();
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

But I don't if I need to replace the `openSearch` with the code for a transition. Any help would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I add an ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971120/should-i-add-an-id)

Comment: That's what I tried. Except it didn't work. I'm doing something wrong @K.C.

Comment: You just add an Click Listener when an Option gets selected. The Code is a bit confusing. When an Option is selected you can listen to this in the onOptionsItemSelected Method, any Button somewhere else need an listener which you should register after you inflate the layout in that fragment

Comment: So remove `openSearch` with `Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);


switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, Login.class);

startActivity(intent);

}

});


}`? @Kitesurfer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you use that button there is it need!

That must work without any button like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_new1:

          Intent intent = new Intent( getActivity(), Login.class);
          getActivity().startActivity(intent);

          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same issue.

Comment: sorry just get it, you are in a fragment not activity, you must get parent activity "getActivity()" and pass it in intent constructor :) , check my edit it must work fine, Login must be an activity too